# why blender motion track didn't render the movie?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, motion-capture

I build a motion tracking animation, but the render result didn't shows my video. I make sure my nodes are linked right. what's wrong with my animation? please help me!

[image][image]

Comment: Make sure that you have Transparent enabled in Render Settings > Film.

Comment: ohhhhh thanks! you helped me a lot !